# Hide div doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have div which it is hidden by default , when the use clicks show link the following javascript method is called:

```
function ChangeControlVisibility(elementID) {
    var  element = $("#" + elementID);
    if (element.css('display') != 'block' && element.css('display') != 'table') {
        element.show();
        var tempElement = $('div.expanded');
        if (tempElement.length > 0) {
            tempElement.css('background-image', 'url(../images/arrow1.gif)');
        }
    }
    else {
        element.hide();
        var tempElement = $('div.expanded');
        if (tempElement.length > 0) {
            tempElement.css('background-image', 'url(../images/arrow2.gif)');
        }  
    } 
}
```

this step works but when i call the previous method at page_load event the method doesn't work:
element.css('display') undefined.

Is there any problem at the previous code????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you execute that code within the `.ready()` handler?

And by the way, unless you really need to explicitly check for display-state `table`, you could just ask for

```
$(document.ready(function(){
   if (!element.is(':visible')){
   }
   else{
   }
});
```

Ref.: [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/), [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it overall by using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), like this:

```
function ChangeControlVisibility(elementID) {
  var vis = $("#" + elementID).toggle().is(':visible');
  $('div.expanded').css('background-image', 'url(../images/arrow' + (vis ? '1' : '2') + '.gif)');
}
```

This toggles the visibility (via `.hide()`/`.show()` under the covers) and checks the resulting visibility to see if it's shown in the page or not, and sets the arrow image according to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the :hidden and :visible jQuery selector. and try something like this:

function ChangeControlVisibility(elementID) {
    var  hiddenElement = $("#" + elementID + ":hidden");
    var  element = $("#" + elementID);
    if (hiddenElement.length > 0) { //to check if this element exists
        hiddenElement.show();
        var tempElement = $('div.expanded');
        if (tempElement.length > 0) {
            tempElement.css('background-image', 'url(../images/arrow1.gif)');
        }
    }
    else {
        element.hide();
        var tempElement = $('div.expanded');
        if (tempElement.length > 0) {
            tempElement.css('background-image', 'url(../images/arrow2.gif)');
        }
    } 
}

Comment: thanks for replay but the problem is i want to register jquery method after c# validation at page_load , at this point element is undefined